# NGUI Object zOrder with Spine zOrder issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui, spine

I have the following scene structure

[image]

SpineHero has order in Layer = 1, and when run, I have

[image]

SpineHero is over NGUIHero and NGUIVS

I want to make the zOrder: NGUIVS - SpineHero - NGUIHero, but I don't know how. If I change order in Layer of SpineHero to 0, I will get

[image]

I read some information about renderQueue, but no luck.
I'm using Unity 5.3.5, NGUI 3.5.2

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to solve my problem.

1. Create Layer0, Layer1, Layer2 are NGUI Panel
2. Set Order in Layer of SpineHero to 1
3. Set Sort Order of layers:

   - Layer0 (VS): Sort Order = 0
   - Layer1 (NGUI Hero): Sort Order = 2
   - Layer2 (Spine Hero): Sort Order = 1

And bellow is my result:

[image: My result]